# How to expose EJB JAX-WS web method to receive object of commonj.SDO DataObject type

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, sca

I'm almost new to web services in Java.
Our company has previously used IBM Process Server to handle the interactions between SCA objects. Due to some reasons we've decided to give up IBM Process Server and therefore we started to migrate our current integrations to EJB.
Just to make myself more clear I've attached a simple schema describing my current task. This is a process deployed at IBM Process Server:

[image: The schema]

I need to develop an EJB, which also acts as a JAX-WS web service and receives an SDO DataObject from the JAX-WS client service, then makes some additional logic and sends the SOAP-request to another web service.
I'm totally don't know how to make my EJB receive a DataObject via SOAP. I have a WSDL-file, describing SOAP request and response formats.
I also found an [article](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-jax-ws-webservice), describing the way to solve this using IBM RAD JAX-RPC webservice from a WSDL with an SDO facade, but the article seems to be outdated.
Is there any way to create the service without using JAXB-bounded POJOs, but with SDO? In case of no, how to handle it using JAXB in a proper way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
During my searchings I figured out, that it's neccessary to generate a bean skeleton, change all the web methods signatures to receive and return JAXB-binded POJOs, generated from WSDL and then transforming it to Data Objects if needed.
JAXB takes care of the all marshalling/unmarshalling staff. I just needed to RTFM a little bit.